# Enviar arquivos entre diferentes sites em ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo um área de acesso para o cliente onde toda a administração do site é feita através dela. Todas as paginas são criadas dinamicamente fazendo requisições em um arquivo especifico no site do cliente. Inclusive os formulários de inclusão de arquivos estão apontando para o site do cliente e não para a própria área de acesso, porém quando tento dar Request.Files no lado do cliente ele vem NULL. Existe alguma solução para isso funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funciona da mesma maneira que um submit interno. Só não se pode esquecer de colocar o atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, configurar o atributo `method='post'` no form e assegurar-se que o botão de `submit` não possua o atributo `formmethod`.